# Как поменять строки в матрице?

Tags: c++, c

В матрице размером N*M поменять местами строку содержащую элемент с наибольшим значением со строкой содержащей элемент с наименьшим значением-это задание. минимум и максимум я нашёл осталось только поменять строки содержащие эти элементы. Подскажите как это сделать ? Может эту программу можно написать как нибудь по проще ? Помогите пожалуйста!

```
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "math.h"
#include "Unit1.h"

#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner) { }

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    const Nmax=5;
    typedef double mas2[Nmax][Nmax];
    mas2 a;
    int i,t,r,j,k,N,imax,jmax,max,min,imin,jmin;
    Memo1->Clear();
    StringGrid1->Cells[0][0]="A";
    StringGrid2->Cells[0][0]="A";
    N=5;
    for(int i=0; i<=N; i++){
        StringGrid1->Cells[0][i]="i="+IntToStr(i);
        StringGrid2->Cells[0][i]="i="+IntToStr(i);

        for(int j=0; j<=N; j++){
            StringGrid1->Cells[j][0]="j="+IntToStr(j);
            StringGrid2->Cells[j][0]="j="+IntToStr(j);
        }
    }
    N=StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
    StringGrid1->RowCount=N+1;
    StringGrid1->ColCount=N+1;
    StringGrid2->RowCount=N+1;
    StringGrid2->ColCount=N+1;

    randomize();
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=N;j++){
            a[i][j]=random(100);
            StringGrid1->Cells[j][i]=FloatToStrF(a[i][j],ffFixed,5,0);
        }
    }
    max=fabs(a[0][0]);imax=1;jmax=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=N;j++){
            if (a[i][j]>max){
                max=a[i][j];
                imax=i;
                jmax=j;
            }
        }
    }
    min=fabs(a[1][1]); imin=1;jmin=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=N;j++){
            if (a[i][j]<min){
                min=a[i][j];
                imin=i;
                jmin=j;
            }
        }
    }
    t=imin;
    r=imax;
    Memo1->Clear();
    Memo1->Lines->Add("MAX = "+FloatToStrF(max,ffFixed,5,0));
    Memo1->Lines->Add("C "+IntToStr(imax));
    Memo1->Lines->Add("MIN = "+FloatToStrF(min,ffFixed,5,0));
    Memo1->Lines->Add("C "+IntToStr(imin));
}
```

Comment: Намекаю: каждая строка в матрице имеет некоторый адрес (какой?). Может быть поменять эти адреса?

Comment: Немного не понимаю, можете показать на примере ?

Comment: @BuilderC: это в таблице типа `double [Nmax][Nmax]`?

@LovelyCat: вам придётся поэлементно переставлять данные в массивах: нулевой элемент с нулевым, первый с первым, и т. д. Как обычно, через временную переменную.

ЗЫ: А почему у вас в профиле женское имя[,](/questions/264771/) а в вопросе вы говорите о себе в мужском роде?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам просто надо поменять местами две строки, используйте `swap` в цикле. Количество повторений цикла — это длина строки. Можно просто через третью переменную.

```
for (int i = 0; i < длина_массива; i++)
{
    t = m[k][i];
    m[k][i] = m[s][i];
    m[s][i] = t; 
}
```

где `k` и `s` — строки, которые вам надо поменять местами.